# ng-clickの引数について

Tags: monaca, angularjs

ng-clickの引数は複数設定することは可能でしょうか？

```
ng-click="click(引数1, 引数2)"
```

このような形で、clickに対し、引数を2つ渡したいです。
どうぞ宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

可能です。
引数を2つ取る`click(arg1, arg2)`というメソッドを`$scope`に作成し、`ng-click`に指定すれば良いです。下記のスニペットを実行してみてください。

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope.click = function(arg1, arg2){
    alert(arg1 + arg2);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
<button ng-click="click(1, 2)">Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: JavaScriptの基本ですね…
お恥ずかしい限りです。
回答有り難うございました。